# Java Regex - How to replace a pattern starts with and ends with

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I have 2 Scenarios:

1. String Starts with Sample Country ! i.e. **Sample Country ! Test Data**

I want a regex to replace Sample Country ! with Empty String, Country here is not fixed, it can be US, France etc

I tried:

```
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("^(Sample[^!]+!)", ""));
```

I am getting the Output

```
! Test Data
```

whereas I just want

```
Test Data
```

2. String ends with Sample Country ! i.e. **Test Data Sample Country !**
   here also I just want

   Test Data

Can someone help to provide the correct Regular expression with the explanation. Thanks a lot

Comment: The regex in your first scenation returns a space followed by `Test Data` see https://ideone.com/wVLloT. You might update the regex to `^Sample[^!]+!\\s*` as you don't need the capturing group if you are replacing it with an empty string and you match 0+ times a trailing whitespace character as well. But for the second scenario, how would you know the difference between `Test Data` and  `Sample Country` if the country name is one or two words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex here:

```
String[] testcases = new String[] {
    "Sample foo ! Test Data", 
    "Sample bar ! Test Data", 
    "Test Data Sample foo !", 
    "Test Data Sample bar !"
};

for (String str : testcases) {
    System.out.println(str.replaceAll("(.* ?)(Sample[a-zA-Z ]+ ! ?)(.*)", "$1$3"));
}
```

Explanation:

```
(.* ?) // first match group, matches anything, followed by an optional space

(Sample[a-zA-Z ]+ ! ?) // second match group, matches the String "Sample followed by a series of letters (your country), a whitespace, an exclamation mark and an optional space

(.*) // third match group, matches anything
```

So the second match group ($2) will contain your "Sample Country" string and we can just replace the result with only the first ($1) and the third ($3) match group.

Answer (score 0):

Edit :

let's make a better way.  you will have not only 2 cases you will have 3 cases

1. **(pattern + data)**  --->  ^Sample[^!]+! **(pattern)** ([^!]) **(data)**
2. (**data +pattern)** ---> ([^!]) **(data)**   Sample[^!]+!$ **(pattern)**
3. **(pattern + data + pattern)** ---> (^Sample[^!]+! **(pattern)** ([^!]) **(data)** Sample[^!]+!$ **(pattern)**

so we have to check all the cases in our string with regex.  we need OR cases in regex it is "|"   another thing is  we have to avoid  not matched cases must be ignored  it is with (?:(regex)) [descripted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do)

```
public class HelloWorld {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] testcases = new String[] {
        "Sample foo ! Test1 Data",
        "Sample bar ! Test2 Data",
        "Test3 Data Sample foo !",
        "Test4 Data Sample bar !",
        "Sample bar ! Test5 Data Sample bar !"
    };

    for (String str: testcases) {
        System.out.println(str.replaceAll("(?:(^Sample[^!]+!([^!])))|(?:(([^!])Sample[^!]+!$))|(?:(^Sample[^!]+!([^!]))Sample[^!]+!$)", "$2$4").trim());
    }

}
```

}
we used your regex and make a new regex after grouping data will be at ($2,$4) groups because of that we replace the string with 2nd and 4th group values.  I hope this will help.
[compile code online](http://tpcg.io/vNhoIF)

Comment: downvote . why ?  "I want a regex to replace Sample Country ! with Empty String, Country here is not fixed, it can be US, France et . "   and here is the answer .  if you have samples  you have the describe  whole data  example